# Pocketsphinx - Code::Blocks, windows crashing

Tags: codeblocks, cmusphinx

I am trying to run this tutorial: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx.
I built both sphinxbase and pocketsphinx on VS 2013. I tried to compile my code on both VS and Code::Blocks. The executable made by VS runs as expected, but the one from Code::Blocks causes the cmd to crash when executing:

```
rv = ps_decode_raw(ps, fh, "goforward", -1);
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?